# Setup wsgi.py at pythonanywhere

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, pythonanywhere

I have wsgi.py problem, can anyone help me with this?

My breadcrumb structure is: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/alinecatikoc/files/var/www/alinecatikoc_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py?edit

My `wsgi.py` file inside is like this:

```
import sys
#
## The "/home/alinecatikoc" below specifies your home
## directory -- the rest should be the directory you uploaded your Flask
## code to underneath the home directory.  So if you just ran
## "git clone git@github.com/myusername/myproject.git"
## ...or uploaded files to the directory "myproject", then you should
## specify "/home/alinecatikoc/myproject"
path = '/home/alinecatikoc/flaskai/app.py'
if path not in sys.path:
   sys.path.insert(path)

import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
project_folder = os.path.expanduser(path)  # adjust as appropriate
load_dotenv(os.path.join(project_folder, '.env'))

from flaskai import app as application
application = app
```

My error log is at the https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/alinecatikoc/files/var/log/alinecatikoc.pythonanywhere.com.error.log:

```
2022-08-11 19:31:47,880: Error running WSGI application
2022-08-11 19:31:47,882: NameError: name 'app' is not defined
2022-08-11 19:31:47,883:   File "/var/www/alinecatikoc_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 89, in <module>
2022-08-11 19:31:47,883:     application = app
2022-08-11 19:31:47,883: ***************************************************
2022-08-11 19:31:47,883: If you're seeing an import error and don't know why,
2022-08-11 19:31:47,883: we have a dedicated help page to help you debug: 
2022-08-11 19:31:47,883: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/
2022-08-11 19:31:47,883: ***************************************************
2022-08-11 19:31:52,038: Error running WSGI application
2022-08-11 19:31:52,038: NameError: name 'app' is not defined
2022-08-11 19:31:52,038:   File "/var/www/alinecatikoc_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 89, in <module>
2022-08-11 19:31:52,039:     application = app
2022-08-11 19:31:52,039: ***************************************************
2022-08-11 19:31:52,039: If you're seeing an import error and don't know why,
2022-08-11 19:31:52,039: we have a dedicated help page to help you debug: 
2022-08-11 19:31:52,039: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/
2022-08-11 19:31:52,039: ***************************************************
2022-08-11 19:39:16,449: Error running WSGI application
2022-08-11 19:39:16,450: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
2022-08-11 19:39:25,030: Error running WSGI application
2022-08-11 19:39:25,032: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
2022-08-11 19:39:26,579: Error running WSGI application
2022-08-11 19:39:26,579: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

My problem is, first, the website doesn't work. Second is I can not figure it out will be my sqlalchemy and db work or not?

and finally my file structure is:

```
/home/
  alinecatikoc/
    flaskai/
      app.py
      requirements.txt
      aiusers.db
      .env
      .emv
      .gitignore
```

Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: remove `application = app` - you don't have `app` because you imported it as `app as application` - so now it has name `application`, not `app`

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. I have changed my structure as you told and it worked! Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove `application = app`.

You don't have `app` because you imported it as `app as application` - so now it has name `application`, not `app`.

---

Documentation on `pythonanywhere.com` also shows it without `application = app`

See: [Flask - configuring-the-wsgi-file](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/Flask#configuring-the-wsgi-file)

---

But your structure suggests that you should import from `flaskai.app`

```
from flaskai.app import app as application
```